# comparing two objects with same parent abstract class and the output is zero

Tags: java, compareto

i have an abstract class that implements comparable  and has the following :

```
public abstract class Figure  implements Comparable{

    protected double height ;

    public abstract double getArea();   

    public abstract double calculatevolume();//will be used later to compare the volume

    public int compareTo(Figure o) {
        return 0;

    }   
}
```

i have  circle and square as  children of  Figure but when i try to compare to volume of two objects it always return 0 !

this is my compareTo  method in the circle class:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {

    Figure a = (Figure) o;

    if (this.calculatevolume() > ((Figure) o).calculatevolume())
        return (int)this.calculatevolume();
    else if (this.calculatevolume() < ((Figure) o).calculatevolume())
        return (int) a.calculatevolume();

    else

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look into raw types, then try to never use them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work better, but first please check your implementation of method `calculatevolume` weather that might return 0.

And please provide argument to comparable interface     `public abstract class Figure  implements Comparable<Figure>`

```
Figure circle = new Circle();
Figure square = new Square();
circle.compareTo(square);



public int compareTo(Figure a) {
        if (this.calculatevolume() > a.calculatevolume())
            return (int)this.calculatevolume();
        else if (this.calculatevolume() < a.calculatevolume())
            return (int) a.calculatevolume();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I made some changes, with arguments in compareTo method and also, definig argument for comparable interface, so a is not neccesary to be casted.

Comment: it seems that the problem in my method 

it seems now that i have a problem with my method

calculatevolume() it returns 0  and i'm sure it overrides the main one .

Comment: edit your question and paste there your calculatevolume method maybe we can help or try debugging your code ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the raw version of the `Comparable` interface here

```
public abstract class Figure  implements Comparable{
```

In other words, you haven't provided a type argument to `Comparable`. As such, it expects a method declared as

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
```

but your class is `abstract` so it doesn't complain. The method you provided

```
public int compareTo(Figure o) {
```

is completely unrelated to `Comparable`. You would see this if you annotated it with `@Override`.

In your child class, you provided

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
```

which is the expected method (which overloads the paren'ts). But not the one you are calling.

You are probably using it as

```
Figure one = ...
Figure two = ...

one.compareTo(two);
```

Because the declared type of `two` is `Figure`, it will use the parent overloaded implementation which expects a `Figure`, and always returns 0.

A solution is to provide an appropriate type argument to `Comparable`.

```
public abstract class Figure  implements Comparable<Figure>{
```

and to work from there.